# Does anyone know of a simple tutorial for Googles Federated Login

Tags: authentication, codeigniter, federated-identity

Im looking for a step by step tutorial that covers Google's Federated Login process using php and cURL. All needs to get dumped into codeIgnitor so it really needs to be easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tutorial, but there's at least one [existing library](http://www.andrewpeace.com/php-google-login-class.html) that is specifically targeted at this; perhaps looking at its code is a good place to start?

See the [Google Federated Login API](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/browse_thread/thread/5e93c8a1378e9d34) group for more discussion about this class.

At its core, the Federated Login API is OpenID, and there are [lots of libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) that will do OpenID. You might want to start with one of those. I clicked on the [first listed PHP library](http://www.openidenabled.com/php-openid/); it has a [demo site](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/trunk/examples/consumer/) which I've verified works with Google's Federated Login (by manually supplying `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` as the URL; or by supplying `http://google.com/profiles/<<username>>`)

(StackOverflow's login page provides a big "Google" button - all that does is fill in `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` as the OpenID url and then submit the form)

Comment: Thanks again James - I really don't like that lib, there must be a more simplified way.